# Java anagram finder algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, anagram

I have an array of `Strings` in Java. I need to find anagrams from the array and print them to the screen.

I am having difficulty with the part where I am supposed to compare array elements to check if they're anagrams or not. How would I do this? I would have to make a loop to go through the array obviously.

I think that I could sort the `String`s and then compare them (since if they're anagrams, they would contain the same letters in the same order when sorted), but how would I unsort them to get the original word?

Answer (score 4):

If you alphabetize the letters than hash them, they should be the same...

```
Map<String, List<String>> words = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for(String word : incomingWords) {
   final String key = alphabetize(word);
   if(words.contains(key)){
      words.get(key).add(word);
   } else {
      words.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
      words.get(key).add(word);
   }
}
```

Now you have `Map` of words that are anagrams... You will also have `List`s in the `Map` that only have 1 entry, you can remove those from the map to just keep a `Map` of ones that have other anagrams from your dictionary...

Comment: Just had a phone interview with Amazon and this was the exact question they asked. Interesting problem if you have more than 10 minutes to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` that maps an ordered `String` to a `Collection` of array indices that are anagrams of the ordered `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2){

    if (str1.length() != str2.length())
        return false;
   
        char[] s1=str1.toCharArray();
        char[] s2=str2.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(s1);
        Arrays.sort(s2);

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
            if(s1[i] !=s2[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: A brief explanation will help others  understand your answer.